# SSIS Package is not running from stored Proc?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SSIS Package when iam trying to execute from SP iam getting wiered error but it was running fine from MSBI.

Sp is

```
EXEC @intErrCode = master..xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /sq Loadnewtables /De 99999'
```

Output is

```
but I keep getting the following error:

Could not load package "My_Package" because of error 0xC0014062.
Description: The LoadFromSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x
004005 (Login timeout expired). The SQL statement that was issued has failed.
```

Comment: Does it work when you run it from a job on the same server ? 
The connections are Windows Auth in your package ?

Comment: to verify:  the package  loadnewtables/my_package  Had been deployed to the same server as the stored procedures  at the root/msdb  level

Answer (score 1):

Well error is very self-explanatory. When you load package from DB, and do not use “/User” and “ /Password” options, windows authentication is used to load that package.
So that brings up check needs to be done around users and permission. Check the windows user exists with right permission.

I am assuming you are on the same machine where this DB is located.
For instance you have the DB server where this DB is with the package and you login to your local machine and connect to SSMS to execute this.  this will result in trying to load package using windows login that you logged in in to your local machine. which might not be exists on the DB server (let’s say you do not have full access to that server.)
So to make it simpler on testing side call with SQL authentication method and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an user/password issue. It might be due to following issues:
 - Check your right on the server.
- Check your authentication mode ( window/user)
- Trying run locally.

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to this [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/783291/ssis-package-fails-to-start-application-lock-timeout-in-ssisdb-catalog-create-execution#tabs) - there is a sp in the SSISDB database in SQL Server 2012 causing packages to time out before they start running.  I had error message "Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904" and "Description: The operation failed because the execution timed out" when calling multiple (more than 10) packages from my scheduling tool via DTExec.  Please vote for the issue on the connect site so that MS can release an official fix.

Comment: thanks for this.  It's not the bug for this particular ticket, but that connect item you point at is exactly what I needed!